# Querying collection created by an app in another Meteor js app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections, document

I have 2 apps that query the same db, they both created diff collections on a db. App A at `myapp:3000` created a collection `comments` while app B at `myapp:3300` created `courses` at its end in the same db (`school`). both servers are running, how do I query the a collection created by app A in app B?

My reason for asking this question is that, as a newbie, it is easy for me to query new collection created in an app by using it global variable. Let's say I created

```
UsesList = new Mongo.Collection('useslist');
```

it is possible for me to publish it this way:

```
Meteor.publish('UsesList', function () {
        if (!this.userId) {
            return false;
            throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized');
        } else {
            return UsesList.find();
        }
    });
```

I wouldn't have access to this variable, and I think accessing the database directly to query the collection might be unethical.

Comment: Are both apps using the same mongo db instance/cluster as backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem in "creating" the same collection in two different applications.

The collection identity is determined by the name string you provide to the collection constructor, and the identity of the database itself, of course.

You can assign them to whatever variable identifier you want, and they may be different between the applications.

I would, however, recommend you to start using ES6 modules and reduce global namespace pollution. Start using the best practices when you are learning, so you won't have to unlearn the bad ones later.

So, provided both apps are connected to the same DB:

```
// same in app 1 and app 2
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const UsesList = new Mongo.Collection('user_list');

// and importing it
import { UserList } from '../path/to/other/file';
```

Comment: I read that this feature works for `Meteor version 1.3+`, I'm on version `1.2.1`, and afraid to upgrade so as not to break things, it didn't work . Any other suggestion as it relates to version 1.2.1. Thanks for this great help

Comment: So do it without the modules features. Simply define it the same way in both apps. Have you tried it? If it does not work, are you sure the *same* DB is indeed used? Of course, two local DBs with the same name on different machines will not work.